# Convert date from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yy using xsl

Tags: date, xslt

HI all,
I got a JavaScript function to convert the date, but I was wondering if there is any way to convert the date with xsl without using JavaScript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all of you for answering my question, after looking on those links you left me to take a look I came out with something very simple.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//MaternityDiaryEvent/DateOfVisit">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(.,9,2),'/',substring(.,6,2),'/',substring(.,3,2))"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Thanks again to all, I'll give you a vote to each of you.

Cesar.

Answer (score 1):

[The `format-date` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-format-date) might do the job.

Answer (score 1):

and the string manipulation, http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/05/01/xslt-string.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the Microsoft formatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256099.aspx).

Or [the `format-date` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-format-date), if you are using XSLT 2.0 (which .Net does not).

Answer (score 0):

Found a very good post on date formatting [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/workdog/archive/2007/02/08/105858.aspx).

No Javascript required. 
Only XSL elements and XPath String functions can do the job.